# How to automatically access shared folders with joined domain PCs

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2

In my workplace, I have a domain on Windows Server 2008 R2 with multiple shared folders and multiple PCs joined to that domain.

The logged-in domain users had some issues when trying to access shared folder as they were prompted for their usernames and passwords that they already logged-in with.

Someone advised to set a static DNS to point to the server, that worked well on the PCs with static IPs. However, The PCs connected through DHCP still prompts for username and passwords.

Is there any way to solve this issue other than setting a static DNS?

Answer (score 0):

Well, your DHCP server should be setting the correct DNS settings to point to your DNS server that can resolve your AD domain and your file server. As a workaround, you can update the host file of your DHCP client workstations. This won't resolve your DNS issue but might bypass them.

Comment: It requires two DNSs, Primary & Secondary, I set the first to the Windows Server 2008 R2 machine with AD. And the second to the router/gateway IP. 

However, some issues arose:

[1] Some users experienced problems while accessing Gmail website, an error message appears on Google Chrome with DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

[2] Problems while accessing the share server (the same  Windows Server 2008 R2 server) with its sharename, having to access it with the IP address.

Comment: [3] Some website filtering had been set in the gateway and worked well prior to that setting, now it appears that the DNS server somehow bypasses the filtering!

Comment: You should have your router gateway IP configured in AD DNS as a forward and only point your desktops to AD.

Comment: Desktops have three settings (Gateway, Preferred DNS server, Alternate DNS server). I understand that you recommend leaving the gateway pointing to the same, point the preferred DNS server to the AD, leave the Alternate DNS server blank) is that right?

Regarding the router gateway, IP configuration in AD DNS as a forward can you please refer to a link on how it could be done.

Comment: Also, we actually have 2 gateway routers:

[1] one for DHCP with unlimited download quota.
[2] the other for static users with Limited download quota, this is where I need website filtering, and it is set on the router gateway itself, the first gateway should remain with no filter.

How could that work in the AD DNS? Is it possible?

Comment: Noting that this is the purpose, if there is any other way to reach the same purpose I will be glad to follow it!

Comment: From a client perspective, client-side DNS configuration assumes that all IP addresses you configure for DNS resolution are equivalent and provide the same results. Multiple IPs are for redundancy. Mixing DNS resolving IP addresses that provide different answers results in, well, different randomized and inconsistent results. Because of your setup and the two different gateways, you might want to setup AD to use external DNS or have the gateways forward to AD DNS.

Comment: Can you please refer to guide on:
[1] Setup AD to use external DNS 
[2] Have the gateways forward to AD DNS